# Is keyword 'event' optional in C#?

Tags: c#, events, compiler-construction

What is the difference between eventOne (with keyword 'event') and eventTwo (w/o keyword)?

```
class Program
{
    public event EventHandler eventOne;
    public EventHandler eventTwo;

    public void RaiseOne()
    {
        if (eventOne != null)
            eventOne(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    public void RaiseTwo()
    {
        if (eventTwo != null)
            eventTwo(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var p = new Program();
        p.eventOne += (s, e) => Console.WriteLine("One");
        p.eventTwo += (s, e) => Console.WriteLine("Two");
        p.RaiseOne();
        p.RaiseTwo();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

- `eventOne` is a public *event* backed by a private field of type `EventHandler`.
- `eventTwo` is a public *field* of type `EventHandler`.

Basically an event *only* encapsulates the ideas of "subscribe" and "unsubscribe" in the same way that a property only encapsulates the ideas of "get" and "set" rather than the actual storage. (As far as the CLR is concerned an event can also expose a "raise" method, but C# never uses this. Ignore it.)

See [my article on events](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/events.html) ([alternate link](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter2/Events.aspx)) for more about the difference between delegates and events.

Comment: Have you had a look at actual IL? You will be amazed.

Comment: Yes, I have. What amazed you?

Comment: While 'add' and 'remove' are actually generated, compiler optimized them out, so in the code above the only difference will be access modifiers on delegates.

Comment: No, the compiler isn't "optimising them out". *Within* the class, eventOne refers to the field. From *outside* the class, it refers to the event.

Comment: (See section 10.8.1 of the C# 3.0 spec for more details.)

Answer (score 17):

By using the **event** keyword you tell C# go generate to hidden methods, **add_XXX** and **remove_XXX** for your underlying delegate. This makes sure that anyone using your class can only attach and remove delegates to the event. The key point is that nobody outside your class and raise the event, so you've got complete control over when this will happen.

If you don't use **event** then you're just exposing a public delegate that anyone can add to, remove from and invoke. It's highly unlikely that you want anyone other than your class to do the invoking.

Comment: So the reason Prankster's code shows no apparent difference is because all the actions on eventOne and eventTwo were performed within the same class? Code that accessed them from a different class would illustrate the difference?

Answer (score 9):

This is the program for illustrating the difference, taking into account the answers before

```
using System;
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var a = new A();
        a.eventOne += (s, e) => Console.WriteLine("One");
        a.eventTwo += (s, e) => Console.WriteLine("Two");
        a.RaiseOne();
        a.RaiseTwo();
                // won't compile
        a.eventOne(null, EventArgs.Empty);
        a.eventTwo(null, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

}

class A {
    public event EventHandler eventOne;
    public EventHandler eventTwo;

    public void RaiseOne()
    {
        if (eventOne != null)
            eventOne(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    public void RaiseTwo()
    {
        if (eventTwo != null)
            eventTwo(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```